# Solr extract text from image and imagePdf files

Tags: solr, ocr, tesseract, apache-tika

I am working with Solr-6.5.1, I want to extract text from Image file and ImagePdf file.for this i installed TesseractOcr and configured this with solr in two ways:

1.Environment variable is set for TESSDATA_PREFIX = C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR and i used /update/extract request handler to index image with content.

2.I modified the tesseractOCRConfig.properties file  in tika-parsers-1.13 jar file in solr lib to" tesseractPath=C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR" and i used /update/extract request handler to index image/imagePdf with content.

In this two way also i'm not getting any content ,But response giving  only attr_x_parsed_by=org.apache.tika.parser.ocr.TesseractOCRParser.

Any other configuration i need to set for solr to TesseractOcr to extract content for Image/ImagePdf file. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Tika?

Comment: I am using Solr-6.5.1 version , so in that tika version  is  this tika-parsers-1.13. one's i will check with new version of tika.

Comment: I tried with tika-parsers-1.18 version its not working for content.

Comment: Does it work with the standalone Tika App runnable jar? That'll let you narrow down if you have a Tika + Tesseract issue, or a SOLR integration issue

Comment: standalone not returning anything tika+tesseractOcr for imagePdf i tried now.

Comment: I used this command in Tesseract directly its returning content but with tika+tesseract not working for image. \Tesseract-OCR > tesseract.exe E:\folder4\testImage.jpg  "E:\folder4\out.txt"

Comment: See https://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaOCR - sounds like you haven't configured Tesseract for Tika properly

Comment: Thank you, now extraction  is working fine  for Image.That Problem may be because of Tesseract-ocr v40.0.0-beta installation ,when i installed Tesseract-ocr v3.0.0.0 extraction working fine. sorry for late reply.